# C# Form Application - Saving Data to access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

As a group we are working on a project and need to save the data collected in the label in a field in an access database.  However we have been having some troubles with this function.

Here is the code what i have tried so far:

We changed the values from `lbl.View.text` to "1" for testing purposes, but still no luck.

```
    private void complete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\meSch\log.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connStr;

        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        // error is in insert statement somehwhere. 
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (TimeStamp, Interest, TotalTime)" + "VALUES('" + "1" +"', '"+ "1" + "','" + "1" + "');";

        // conn1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\meSch\log.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");

        // cmd = new OleDbCommand("", con);
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", lblView.Text);
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interest", lblView.Text);
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalTime", lblView.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `TimeStamp`, `Interest` and `TotalTime` columns are character typed? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code? Is this query inserts on access itself? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I don't know a single programmer who likes the description of a problem "doesn't work", "still no luck" etc... Learn to ask properly.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Remove the ; (semicolon) from your sql query and put whitespace infront and after VALUES.

Comment: Well then your error lies in the INSERT statement. Did you debug the string to see what it actually produces? I bet you'd see the error right away... The error is really clear `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your exception message, `TimeStamp` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335?wa=wsignin1.0) in MS Access. You need to use it with square brackets like `[TimeStamp]`. As a better way, change it to *non-reserved* word which is meaningful for your column.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users (TimeStamp, Interest, TotalTime)
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    cmd.Parameter.AddwithValue("@p1", "1");
    cmd.Parameter.AddwithValue("@p2", "1");
    cmd.Parameter.AddwithValue("@p3", "1");

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I think he/they know(s) about parametrized queries if you look at the out-commented code. It's changed for testing purposes.

Comment: I agree on the columns, and so many times do I see queries and sometimes even table names as what COULD be reserved words (sometimes they are too), and just screams of headaches...

Comment: @DatRid Yeah, I just wanna mention anyway :)